# Access Kotlin Standard Library from Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

In my Kotlin Multiplatform project, I'm trying to access Kotlin types defined in `kotlin-stdlib` from Swift.

***TL;DR***: StdLib types/methods seem not to result in header definitions, I'd like a solution that doesn't involve writing lots of boilerplate code

### My scenario

I have an interface defined in Kotlin ...

```kotlin
interface MyKotlinInterface {
  fun run() : Sequence<String>
}
```

... and implemented this interface in Swift ...

```swift
class MySwiftClass : MyKotlinInterface {
  func run() -> KotlinSequence {
    // return sequenceOf("foo")
  }
}
```

... there I'm trying to create a `Sequence` but there are no methods from the `kotlin.sequences` package available (e.g. `generateSequence`).

Is it actually possible to access Kotlin framework types or methods beyond what I define in my code -- if yes, how? Furthermore, how can this be achieved without writing boilerplate code?

#### Further details

Having a look into the generated Objective-C header file, I see definitions for my class (obviously) and basic Kotlin types. What's missing is basically everything from the standard library functionality (I care for everything `Sequence`-related).

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.0"
}

kotlin {
    targets { /* ... */ }

    sourceSets {

        getByName("commonMain") {
            dependencies {
                api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
            }
        }

        // ...

        getByName("iosMain") {
            dependencies {
                api("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having the `kotlin-stdlib` defined as a dependency for the iOS target, I would expect those to become actually available from Swift.

#### Minimal working example

https://github.com/panzerfahrer/so-mwe-kotlin-mpp-swift

### Current solution approach

The only solution I came up with, is writing the desired function for the iOS target:

```kotlin
fun <T : kotlin.Any> generateSequence(nextFunction: () -> T?): kotlin.sequences.Sequence<T> = kotlin.sequences.generateSequence(nextFunction)
```

This works *ok-ish* but is highly unsatisfying as it requires lots of boilerplate code. Additionally, extension functions cannot be made available this way and would require more boilerplate code or even rewriting parts of the standard library.

### Desired solution

I like to avoid writing boilerplate code as much as possible. What I actually only care about, is to have (in my case) `Sequence` fully accessible from Swift. My feeling is, it would be sufficient to make the compiler generate selected or all header definitions for the standard library functionality.

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a related [Github issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2249) that basically covers this case.

Comment: Do you really need lazy computation (aka Sequence) in your Kotlin code? If no, I would recommend using List<T> instead (and it maps to Swift). 
For Sequence implementation, a workaround could be to export a factory function from you Kotlin library to help building a sequence on a Swift side

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need lazy computation (aka Sequence) in your Kotlin code? 
If no, I would recommend using `List<T>` instead (and it maps to Swift directly).

For `Sequence` implementation, a workaround could be to export a factory function from your Kotlin library, e.g. you may declare a function like

```
fun <T : kotlin.Any> generateSequence(nextFunction: () -> T?)
    = kotlin.sequences.generateSequence(nextFunction)
```

You may select any other factory function for `Sequence`, that matches your use-case.

In general, there are too many functions in the Kotlin standard library. Exporting them all to Swift will create too many useless symbols in the binary and increase the compilation time.

Comment: That's my current solution (see lower part of question) :-P

Comment: Yep, maybe it makes sense to use `List<T>` not `Sequence`. Your example repo does not win from you using `Sequence<T>`